# how can i display reference of image?

Tags: android, json

This is a json format i am building a app in which i have to show image but in this format, it only give me image reference how can i display image from image reference. I am new in android, please answer me in detail.

```
{
  "html_attributions": [],
  "results": [{
    "geometry": {},
    "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    "id": "b55aeae1579aa5d2313acbda97bbde5d403bfcbe",
    "name": "Emoji Centre Pakistan",
    "photos": [{}],
    "place_id": "ChIJ06t7z3_A3zgRSjlPdn0hrTA",
    "rating": 5,
    "reference": "CmRRAAAAAhNMBwgr1K1YA3B-44ztZPHcaSLMyWH3vhd92jgZmN4WPiIKl7MMVxwa_UlP5-DJKISSKEleVZ9qFMRb0DpLA0w2h2dgn9xkYTMDpG3nxL9VI3MjaMtTa07FFHaE0xXwEhDcNE5uFDpjVvT3Y_g0Fm7TGhTyIcmuumTybtEmTBNMNdySqdwWXA",
    "scope": "GOOGLE",
    "types": [],
    "vicinity": "Ataturk Avenue, Islamabad"
  }],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

Comment: this reference what is it?Are you making call to a Google API? if yes then which? I suggest check the API documentation for this reference value.
To me this reference value seems to be BASE64 encoded image

Comment: yes i am making a call to google api....nearbyplace api

Comment: See my answer below for parsing image url and showing it on imageview using Glide library

Answer (score 0):

In order to display image, you can use Picasso

```
GRADLE
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Java code

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

I advice, use this lib http://square.github.io/picasso/.
Add in the end of your app.gradle in dependencies

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

After in code, add this operation

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Also do not forgot to add internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: i think this is used to display single image.what about many images

Answer (score 0):

```
Glide.with(mContext).load("Your_Url")
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(Your_ImageView);
```

Do not forget to add in build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

**How can i display `reference` of image?**

From `Google Place API` [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details),

**# reference:** — Contains a `token` that can be used to query the Details service in future. This `token` may differ from the reference used in the request to the Details service. It is recommended that stored references for places be regularly updated.

Although this `token` uniquely identifies the place, the converse is not true. A `place` may have many valid `reference tokens`.

**Note:** The `reference` is now `deprecated` in favor of `place_id`. See the [deprecation notice](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#deprecation).

**# If you want to get `icon`, try below steps:**

**1.** Parse the icon `URL` from `JSON` response string.

```
// Icon url
String iconUrl;

try {

    JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray("results");

    JSONObject obj = results.getJSONObject(0); // 0 used for first icon image
    iconUrl = obj.getString("icon"); // "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png"        

} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
}
```

**2.** To show `icon` from `URL` on `ImageView`, use `Glide` library.

**Use of Glide:**

```
// For example
String iconUrl = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png";

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_image_view);

Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
```

**3.** To use `Glide`, you have add following `dependencies` on your `app/build.gradle`:

**app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

See Glide [documentation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

**UPDATE:**

If you want to get place `photos` then you should use array `photos[]`.

**photos[]:** — an `array` of `photo` objects, each containing a `reference` to an `image`. A Place Details request may return up to `ten` photos. More information about place photos and how you can use the `images` in your application can be found in the [Place Photos documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos).

A `photo` object is described as:

```
photo_reference — a string used to identify the photo when you perform a Photo request.
height — the maximum height of the image.
width — the maximum width of the image.
html_attributions[] — contains any required attributions. This field will always be present, but may be empty.
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: actuallu my image is not in png i think it is in string form

Comment: Form you json format, there is an image url "icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png". You have get this url using json parsing technique. See my updated answer for getting image url.

Comment: Well icon is just an icon. It is not an image.

Comment: See my updated answer. Instead of image, reference Contains a token that can be used to query the Details service in future. This token may differ from the reference used in the request to the Details service. It is recommended that stored references for places be regularly updated.

Comment: can i get your skype id??

Comment: Are you getting the point that i mentioned in my updated answer.

Comment: "reference":"CmRRAAAAAhNMBwgr1K1YA3B-44ztZPHcaSLMyWH3vhd92jgZmN4WPiIKl7MMVxwa_UlP5-DJKISSKEleVZ9qFMRb0DpLA0w2h2dgn9xkYTMDpG3nxL9VI3MjaMtTa07FFHaE0xXwEhDcNE5uFDpjVvT3Y_g0Fm7TGhTyIcmuumTybtEmTBNMNdySqdwWXA".................this is not an image data. its a token that can be used to query the Details service in future.

Comment: You can use photos[] - an array of photo objects, each containing a reference to an image. A Place Details request may return up to ten photos. Read details : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos

Answer (score 0):

The response has a JSON Array `photos`. This array is supposed to contain the list of photos uploaded for that place.But in your case it is empty, so it means there is no photo available with google for that place.

You can find more detail [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details).It defines what references are and how you can use it to fetch more detail.